# read data from text box into php var and then echo

Tags: php, variables, textbox, echo, registration

I am new to php and just cant figure how to get the data from a a html textbox and then echo the var.
I am making a registration page, I do everything else but this simple part.
I have a preset value="hi" just for testing if the var populates. 
Fyi in the future it will be done after i click a register button. just need to get this.
Thanks all

```
 <input name="fName" id="fName" type="text" value="hi" />
```

and here is the php which i try to read the data into if the echo is test to check if it populates

```
<?php
$fName = $_POST['fName'];
//$fName = $_GET['fName'];
echo $fName;
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you:

You have to make a form and submit it! After that you can use the variable`$_POST['fName']`

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['fName'])) //if you also want to check if it is empty use !empty($_POST['fName'])
        echo $_POST['fName'];

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="fName" id="fName" type="text" value="hi" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit!" />
</form>
```

Comment: @CormacHallinan Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: You can accept answer how helped you so other people with the same problem find the answer faster!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ echo $_POST['name']; } ?>" />
<input type="text" name="phone"  placeholder="PHONE" value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['phone'])){ echo $_POST['phone']; } ?>" />
```

Comment: While this may answer OPs question, please provide an explanation with your answer.